# Splitting Ruby strings into pages

Tags: ruby

I've been thinking about this problem for a while, and not quite sure the best way to go about it.

In a rails app I have `books`, which have many `chapters`, which have many `sections`. Chapters are basically just containers for sections, though may contain strings of text themselves. The sections hold most of the book text.

I'm planning to build an HTML 5 ebook reader that works in a mobile browser, and I don't want the user to have to scroll down -- I want the text to break at the end of the page.

I'd assumed using `split` might be the way to go, but I'm not sure there's a way to break at regular intervals? Would a javascript option work better here?

I'd looked at this: [Dividing text article to smaller parts with paging in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648551/dividing-text-article-to-smaller-parts-with-paging-in-ruby-on-rails) but can't feasibly insert manual break marks in the text, some of which are 90,000+ words.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Javascript has access to the size of the client window (in pixels). If you send a bunch of text and use CSS so you know the font on the client size, you can divide the client window size by the height of the font to plus the spacing for an estimate of how many lines we can have (do the same for the width). That can't take too much JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that the page length will depend on the device (and possibly the text size, if that is feature of your app). You should probably send large chunks that are sure to be at least say 5 pages long, at a time and then let the javascript do the paging. Rails has no access, nor should it, to the size of the display.

Text requires very little data, you shouldn't worry about transmitting more than you need or keeping too much in memory.

Comment: Okay, I don't have much JS knowledge, so that'll take some work to figure out, but seems like it'll be easier than letting Rails handle the splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You may use blank line("\n" or "
") as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd send enough of the page content down to easily fill a page and more, then use javascript on the client slide to remove sentences from the page until the scroll-bar disappears.

[Resize.js](https://gist.github.com/1084223) is something similar I wrote a while ago. I wanted to enlarge/reduce the font size used on a screen until the screen was just full (for a dashboard monitor).. Yours would be similar, but instead of changing the font size, you are trimming off sentences.

Let me know if you can't see how to adapt this code.

Note: I would also make the javascript note the amount of text it ends up displaying, and pass that to the server in the 'next page' request, so the server knows where to start the next page from.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, and it avoids pulling the entire group of text all at once.